# Elution Rate - Alkanes VS Alkenes in Gas Chromatography

Tags: chromatography

Some references say that alkanes elute faster than alkenes, whereas in my textbook the higher volatility of alkenes means they elute faster than alkanes. This is for gas chromatography.

> Alkenes are more polar than alkanes due to more electron-withdrawing
>   $\text{sp}^2$-hybrid orbitals (more s-character draws electrons closer to
>   nucleus).

Can someone please clarify - bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromatography in general is a separation method in which the partition equilibrium of a compound between two phases is permanently disturbed since one of the phases is changing/exchanged (mobile phase).

Apparently, the mobile phase in gas chromatography is the carrier gas.
The stationary phase isn't just a hollow tube but a capillary covered with various differently functionalized materials, that may be rather unpolar (squalane), more polar (polyethylene glycol) or polar and shape-selective (cyclodextrines). Other very common materials are alkyl-substituted polysiloxanes, such as polydimethylsiloxane.

Using the latter stationary phase, Alan Katritzky and coworkers published *QSPR: the correlation and quantitative prediction of chemical and physical properties from structure*, *Chem. Soc. Rev.*, **1995**, *24*, 279-287 ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/CS9952400279), [PDF](http://www.ark.chem.ufl.edu/published_papers/pdf/377.pdf)). Here, the retention times for dodecane and 1-dodecene were given as 4.59 and 4.45 min, respectively.

Ladislav Sojak published a freely available 35-page review *Separation and identification of isomeric hydrocarbons by capillary gas chromatography and hyphenated spectrometric techniques* in *Petroleum & Coal*, **2004**, *4(3)*, 1-35 ([PDF](http://www.vurup.sk/sites/vurup.sk/archivedsite/www.vurup.sk/pc/vol46_2004/issue3/pdf/Sojak_1_35.pdf)). You might want to have a look at this article on the effect of having **non-terminal** $\ce{C=C}$ double bonds and cis-trans isomers of longer alkenes, which therefore have significantly different shapes.

Comment: ah interesting... so it really depends on the molecule itself then... no general rule of one before the other.

Comment: @confused It's apparently a complex matter of interaction of the compounds with the stationary phase. Have a look at Fig. 9 in the article by Sojak. There, the order of retention times for trans-6-pentadecene and cis-5-pentadecene is reversed when a column with a thicker coating of the same stationary phase is used.